# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetDataStore'

Tags: python

I guys, I developing a utility in python and i have 2 object the main class and an database helper for get sqlserver data.

database.py

```
import _mssql

class sqlserver(object):

    global _host, _userid, _pwd, _db

    def __new__ (self, host, userid, pwd, database):
        _host = host
        _userid = userid
        _pwd = pwd
        _db = database

    def GetDataStore(self, sql):
        conn = _mssql.connect(server='(local)\\sqlexpress', user='sa', password='xxx', database='Framework.Data2')
        conn.execute_non_query('CREATE TABLE persons(id INT, name VARCHAR(100))')
        conn.execute_non_query("INSERT INTO persons VALUES(1, 'John Doe')")
        conn.execute_non_query("INSERT INTO persons VALUES(2, 'Jane Doe')")
```

gaemodel.py

```
import os
import sys
from fwk import system, types, databases

class helper(object):
    pass

def usage(app_name):
    return "Usage: %s <project name>" % (app_name)

def main(argv):
    _io = system.io()

    project_name = argv[1]
    project_home = os.path.join(_io.CurrentDir(), project_name)

    _db = databases.sqlserver('(local)\sqlexpress', 'sa', 'xxx', 'Framework.Data2')    
    _db.GetDataStore("select name from sysobjects where xtype = 'U' and name not like 'Meta%'")

    str = "from google.appengine.ext import db"
    #for row in cur:
    #    str += "class %s" % row["name"]

    print cur

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        main(sys.argv[1:])
    else:
        print usage(sys.argv[0]);
```

My problem is when i try run code return me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projectos\FrameworkGAE\src\gaemodel.py", line 28, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Projectos\FrameworkGAE\src\gaemodel.py", line 18, in main
_    db. GetDataStore("select name from sysobjects where xtype = 'U' and name not like 'Meta%'")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetDataStore'
```

What is wrong ??

Comment: what is this? `_    db`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all:

- The `__new__` method should be named `__init__`.
- Remove the global _host etc. line

Then change the `__init__` method:

```
self.host = host
self.userid = userid
etc.
```

And change `GetDataStore`:

```
conn = _mssql.connect(server=self.host, user=self.userid, etc.)
```

That should do the trick.

I suggest you read a bit on object-oriented Python.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at what [`__new__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__new__#object.__new__) is supposed to be doing and what arguments it's supposed to have. I think you wanted to use `__init__` and not `__new__`. The reason for your particular error is that `_db` is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change databases.py like this:

```
import _mssql

class sqlserver(object):

    def __init__ (self, host, userid, pwd, database):
        self.host = host
        self.userid = userid
        self.pwd = pwd
        self.db = database

    def GetDataStore(self, sql):
        conn = _mssql.connect(server=self.host, user=self.userid, password=self.pwd, database=self.db)
        conn.execute_non_query('CREATE TABLE persons(id INT, name VARCHAR(100))')
        conn.execute_non_query("INSERT INTO persons VALUES(1, 'John Doe')")
        conn.execute_non_query("INSERT INTO persons VALUES(2, 'Jane Doe')")
```